# Is it good design pattern to pass model objects to view objects in java swing MVC?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I have class `Model`:

```
class Model {
Object[][] objects=new Object[3][];
}
```

I have a controller which is action listener:

```
class MyListener implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
          //here I have to get objects array from Model and pass it to view to display
}
}
```

But I worry if I pass objects array to `JPanel` it will cause problems later.

Is there another way for JPanel to use `objects`?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't touched Swing for a very long time, but still: JPanel doesn't really need any kind of model objects, it's just a widget that can aggregate other widgets. Usually, it makes sense to pass the model to widgets that can actually show something, for instance, textArea, textField, tables and so on.

In an MVC model implementation of swing, Components act as both as a view (obviously) and controllers by means of listeners reacting to some events.

In any case, the following rules apply:

- Controllers change the model
- Views are "subscribed" to the model changes. Usually, its implemented in internal models of components in swing itself, but you can extend them and define your behavior. Once model gets changed by controller, it fires special events to views, like "hey, I'm changed".
- Model is usually loosely coupled to views.
- Views react to these events and apply the changes (usually repainting with new data).

From your question its kind of hard to tell what will happen when someone changes the model (not enough information).

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand how to tell view that model is changed? Model is changed by background thread, not by user.

Comment: Check out the observer pattern. Model is Observable here. Model should expose methods for registering Observses. Views are observers in this case. Views get notified that the model has changed. Its doesnt really matter who triggers the change as long as views get notified about these changes